# Vuex Actions Reactivity

Tags: vue.js, action, vuex, vue-reactivity

I discovered strange issue:
action in one vuex component uses getters of other vuex components
but
this action is used nowhere
and it refreshes state of it's vuex component

but it itself refreshes (=is executed) automatically when it's dependencies are refreshed

So I want to know. May I depend on such behavior? And can you please explain how it works?

I widely use in simple Vue computed and methods, and know their reactivity. But this behavior in Vuex actions seems strange to me

Comment: Can you please provide some code examples?